# When i run web based application i.e. configured with the IIS then it gives connection related error

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, web-config

Hi
I have created web based application. I configure with IIS but when its run under iis then it gives error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will be closed.

But its running on local machine correctly.

Whats the problem? Should i change my connection string in Web.config?

Thank you.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\NewOnlineExamDemo25\App_Data\OnlineQuiz.­mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
    <add key="Delay" value="1800000" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\NewOnlineExamDemo25\App_Data\OnlineQuiz.­mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Please Show your connection string settings.

Comment: <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\NewOnlineExamDemo25\App_Data\OnlineQuiz.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
    <add key="Delay" value="1800000" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\NewOnlineExamDemo25\App_Data\OnlineQuiz.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your connection string:

```
 value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\NewOnlineExamDemo25\App_Data\OnlineQuiz.­
```

On the server I don't think that this path; `D:\NewOnlineExamDemo25\App_Data\OnlineQuiz` exists.
You have to attach the DB to your SQL server and then set that information in your connection string.

Comment: i have chaged my path but its working on my pc only not on the other machine with that link : http://(My pc name)/onlineexam/Home.aspx

Comment: can u see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933266/displaying-image-using-image-control-in-button-click-event

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config file for the setting of 'Identity impersonate'. Probably it'll be enough to use the following

```
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
```